# ¿Cómo copiar un dato en la última fila de una columna en especifico con app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Necesito copiar datos de una spreadsheet a otra y por eso no hay problema, el problema es la forma en la que se copian.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
  //Esto es lo que estoy copiando de la otra hoja
  var ss1 = spreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var sheet = ss1.getSheetByName("Nomb");
  var A = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();

  //Esto es para la spreadsheet a la que voy a copiar lo anterior
  var ss = spreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Nombres");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; 


  //Aqui inserto los valores 
  var destRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2, A.length,
   A[0].length).setValues(A);
```

con este código traigo datos de una spreadsheet a otra y con el método `getLastRow + 1` me los copia a la última fila disponible como este ejemplo

`A B C`
`3 3 3`
`1   5`
`8   3`
`2   4`
`# 3`

y con le `getLastRow` los inserta así...

`A B C`
`3 3 3`
`1   5`
`8   3`
`2 3 4`

pero necesito que los inserte en la columna dos pero en el primer espacio disponible que sería en la segunda fila como así...

`A B C`
`3 3 3`
`1 3 5`
`8   3`
`2   4`

He visto ejemplos en los que obtienes el primer espacio disponible de esa columna como el siguiente código que encontré en este tutorial [youtube](http://youtube.com/watch?v=owekshcyvtA).

```
function ultimaFilaCol() {
  var columna = "B";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var maximoFilas = ss.getMaxRows();

  var valores = ss.getRange(columna + "1:" + columna + maximoFilas).getValues();

  for (;valores[maximoFilas-1] == "" && maximoFilas>0; maximoFilas--){}

  Logger.log(maximoFilas);
}
```

Pero no se si el código anterior me puede servir y si sirve, como lo puedo aplicar.

Comment: Ese código de `function ultimaFilaCol()` se supone que busca el ultimo valor disponible en una determinada columna, solo lo busca y al final te das cuenta con el registro, mira te anexo el vídeo de YT de donde lo saque, (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owekshcyvtA) y pues lo que necesito hacer es poder insertar los valores pero que se ajusten a las columnas y no a las filas, como en el mini ejemplo que puse, a lo mejor el código anterior no sirva como lo recalque pero pues no se si alguien le pueda dar utilidad o me ayude con otra forma mas simple, Gracias.

Comment: Ya viendo la explicación de Diego, ya le encuentro sentido al for. Deberías agregar la atribución a al pregunta pues los comentarios son para de solicitar aclaraciones y dar recomendaciones, no para colocar información importante.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, el código de Diego (el autor del video referido) te va a servir.

En

```
var destRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2, A.length, A[0].length).setValues(A);
```

reemplaza `lastRow` por `maximoFilas + 1`

y previo a ello agrega la parte del código de Diego que calcula `maximoFilas`.

Observa que el código de Diego usa `ss` mientras que el tuyo usa `ss1` así que con ajustes mínimos deberías poderlo usar sin problemas.

Comment: Es es lo que estabas buscando ¿o no?

Comment: @LuisAvl Por favor edita tu pregunta para clarificar lo que estas buscando, aunque me parece que tu mismo te estas respondiendo, en lugar del varlor que resulte de getLastRow() lo que necesistas es 1 ¿verdad?

Comment: ya modifique el codigo inicial es que en el ejemplo que puse en el codigo inicial si funciona tu respuesta, una disculpa no me di cuenta que no me explique mejor, pero en el caso de que hubiera mas datos, no, como ya que el `getLastRow`  sin el + 1, inserta los valores en la fila donde se encuentre el ultimo valor detectado y necesito que los inserte en la fila donde encuentre el  ultimo valor detectado pero de una determinada columna, ya que  si los inserta en la columna que quiero pero no en la fila correcta. Gracias por tu ayuda Ruben una disculpa por explicar mal. Espero me ayudes.

Comment: Ahora tengo otro problemilla jeje, resulta que ahora los imprime pero en la ultima fila de esas columnas quiere decir... en la fila 1000 y crea mas filas jeje, estaba viendo si me podía servir `getLastColumn` pero no ya que necesito especificarle la columna, no se si tengas algún otro método? Te agradezco Ruben por tu ayuda.

Comment: @LuisAvl Lo que pasa es que estas usando referencias abiertas sin tener presente las implicaciones de las mismas. Una forma de evitar que causen la mayoría de los problemas es eliminar las filas en blanco de la hoja origen que no requieras. Para más detalles lo apropiado seria que publicaras una pregunta de seguimiento como una nueva pregunta.